# ConnectionNotEstablished error when loading any page

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am getting this `ConnectionNotEstablished` error whenever I try to access any page on my rails app. The error only started to occur when I installed phpMyAdmin and changed my database's password. I updated my `database.yml` file to reflect the change but am still getting this error.

Does anyone have more details about what this error is or how I can go about fixing it?

I am running Ubuntu 10.10, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.1, and connecting with the mysql2 gem.

Comment: sqlite3 is much easier to get started with.

Comment: just to be sure, you restarted the server after the password change, right?

Comment: if you restarted the server as @fablife mentions and it still doesn't work, try connecting using mysql and the same login credentials. If you can see the database then something else is at work. It's worth a try though to see if the permissions are good using a different client.

Comment: Turns out it was a ` hidden in the database.yml file I didn't notice. Fixed it up and the issue resolved itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the database.yml file is properly formed